# Meaning of a part of regex

Tags: regex

I am pretty new to regex. What is the meaning of this expression [A-PR-UWYZ] ?

Comment: All uppercase latin characters except for Q, V and X.

Answer (score -1):

[A-PR-UWYZ] matches the character literally (case sensitive)
Match a single character present in the list below

[A-PR-UWYZ]

•   A-P a single character in the range between A (index 65) and P (index 80) (case sensitive)

•   R-U a single character in the range between R (index 82) and U (index 85) (case sensitive)

•   WYZ matches a single character in the list WYZ (case sensitive)

•   matches the character literally (case sensitive)